# BSD Root Error Virtualbox install Mac OSX

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I am trying to install Mac OSX on Windows XP using virtualbox and keep getting this message: `BSD root: disk1s3, major 14, minor 3`.  I have assigned an 80gb virtual hard drive and have tried other iso files, but get the same message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically installing MAC OSX on a virtual machine is against the EULA. That being said it's not a trivial operation to get OSX running on a VM. You might want to check out [The OSX86 Project](http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)